# inconsistent react material-ui textfield component rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textfield

Exact same line of code renders differently on two pages on the same react project.

```
<TextField id="outlined-search" label="Search field" type="search" variant="outlined" />
```

[Page 1 rendered correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSGoe.png)
[Page 1 Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNi6a.png)

[Page 2 rendered incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUuHy.png)
[Page 2 Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m653S.png)

There is supposed to be the ability to clear the TextField entry but it does not render on one of my pages for some reason. Very puzzling. I tried removing any CSS imports in case there is styling over-ridding but same results. Not quite sure where to go about this because it's just one simple line of code. Underlying problem may be somewhere I am not looking. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you add the TextField code?

Comment: Context please, there has to be more than this one line.

Comment: can you reproduce this in a sandbox/codepen, or do you have a live version?

Comment: Sure! I'm trying to reproduce this on sandbox but I can't reproduce the wrong rendering...

Comment: But in the meanwhile I can try to elaborate the situation. In one page the TextField renders as it should, but when I try to render the TextField in another page, it does not render properly. The TextField code is just that single line and the import line from @material-ui/core.

Comment: I added two code snippets but I am not sure if that will help because the code practically looks identical... Sorry for the lack of context